# Execute DDL to create a native table in BigQuery from files stored on GCS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, ddl, external-tables

I would like to create a native table in BigQuery from a CSV file with DDL statements in a way that replicates the "create table from..." feature in BigQuery's UI as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

My ultimate goal is use the query in a Dataform sqlx file.

When I try to do it with a CREATE TABLE statement, it fails with error `Unknown option: format`.

```
CREATE TABLE `dataset_name.table_name` (
field1 STRING,
field2 STRING
) 

OPTIONS(format = 'CSV',
uris = ['gs://path/to/file.csv'],
field_delimiter = ',',
skip_leading_rows=1);
```

While the query below works fine...

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `dataset_name.table_name` (
field1 STRING,
field2 STRING
) 

OPTIONS(format = 'CSV',
uris = ['gs://path/to/file.csv'],
field_delimiter = ',',
skip_leading_rows=1);
```

...but throws a warning message regarding disabled caching
[image]

Is it only a matter of enabling metadata caching or am I missing something else ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the right SQL function. You have to use `LOAD DATA` as explained in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table)